# How to split a paragraph into two or more paragraphs in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a string $text:

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet.';
```

Now I want to convert this string into multiple paragraphs.I have tried word-wrap 
`echo wordwrap($text,100,"<br />",true);`but It splits the string after every 100 character and is giving an odd look as it does not take care of full stops or words.
the new paragraph is often not organized.

Is there a way to split the paragraphs fairly well in two or more well-formatted paragraphs.
I Hope I have made the description clear.

Comment: drop the last parameter or set it to false. Refer to the docs in case of doubts http://php.net/manual/de/function.wordwrap.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to split the string after every X amount of words. This for instance, would split your $text after every 50 words and add them to paragraphs:

```
preg_replace( '~((?:\S*?\s){50})~', "<p>$1</p>", $text );
```

Comment: Hey thanks I tried this one It is generating a little problem

Comment: It is breaking the sentence too. for eg  Mauris

iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio.  Now it is a single sentence but the word "Mauris" remains in the first paragraph and other moves to the next paragraph.. Have I made you clear about my problem?

Comment: Then the regular expression needs to be changed to look for every nth occurance of a punctuation for example. Lets say that you want a paragraph after five occurances of ".". I dont have time to cook that one up just now, but Ill come back a bit later when I have lunch.

Answer (score 1):

It's nice to look at the docs. :)

```
<?php
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet.'; 
echo wordwrap($text,100,"<br />");
```

**Output**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit<br />arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut<br />in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse<br />dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa, ut<br />blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia<br />dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br />Nullam in dui mauris. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus<br />rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non<br />venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere.<br />Praesent id metus massa, ut blandit odio. Proin quis tortor orci. Etiam at risus et justo dignissim<br />congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet.
```

Comment: Thanks @Surjit . I want to split the paragraph fairly.Actually this is my first question on stackoverflow. I think i have not made the problem clear. I will just add an image to make it clear